# JavaScript Map Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, maps

array called 'notes' contains 5 objects , each object has keys

```
var notes = [
   {
       title: "Home",
       message: "is a good story",
       status: 'new',
       author:"dala",
   },
   {
       title: "School",
       message: "Have to go everday",
       status: 'new',
       author:"aisha",
   },
   {
       title: "study",
       message: "we have exam to pass",
       status: 'new',
       author:"Omar",
   },
   {
       title: "Work",
       message: "dead line is close",
       status: 'new',
       author:"Said",
   },
   {
       title: "homework",
       message: "as today we need to do it",
       status: 'new',
       author:"Amal",
   },
];
```

i want to update all the notes's status to be 'completed',  the error is  the code only update the first Object

```
function map(notes,callback){
   const newNotes =[];
   for(var i=0; i<notes.length; i++) {
       const result = callback(notes[i].status = "completed",i);
       newNotes.push(result);
       return newNotes;
   }
}
var outp = map(notes,function(value, i){
   console.log(i)
   for(var a= 0; a<value.length; a++){
       return notes;

   }

})
console.log(outp);
```

I was training on the callback function, and this training code was the face of a problem writing the code If you have useful resources to learn from, please share them with me

Comment: It wrong to use `notes[i].status = "completed"` in your callback argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the map function you `returned` the `newNotes` array within the for loop instead of after it. However I would suggest to use the built in `map` function.

```js
var notes = [
   {
       title: "Home",
       message: "is a good story",
       status: 'new',
       author:"dala",
   },
   {
       title: "School",
       message: "Have to go everday",
       status: 'new',
       author:"aisha",
   },
   {
       title: "study",
       message: "we have exam to pass",
       status: 'new',
       author:"Omar",
   },
   {
       title: "Work",
       message: "dead line is close",
       status: 'new',
       author:"Said",
   },
   {
       title: "homework",
       message: "as today we need to do it",
       status: 'new',
       author:"Amal",
   },
];

function map(notes,callback){
   const newNotes =[];
   for(var i=0; i<notes.length; i++) {
       const result = callback(notes[i].status = "completed",i);
       newNotes.push(result);
   }
   return newNotes;
}
var outp = map(notes,function(value, i){
   console.log(i)
   for(var a= 0; a<value.length; a++){
       return notes;
   }
})
console.log(outp);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write your own `map` function, `Array.prototype.map` already does what your `map` function does (and a bit more, but that's not relevant).

The problem is:

- Your `map` does `return newNotes;` **inside** the `for` loop, so it returns when the loop has only done one of the elements.
- `map` isn't calling your callback correctly.
- Your callback isn't doing what the `map` function expects it to.

The call to your callback should be just:

```
const result = callback(notes[i], i);
```

And the `return newNotes;` should be **after** the loop.

Then your callback should create a new object with the properties from the original object passed in, plus `status: "completed"` — perhaps using an object literal with spread syntax, like this:

```
const output = map(notes, function(note, index) {
    return {...note, status: "completed" };
});
```

Comment: I consider he/she is doing practice of callback function?

Comment: @TropicsCold - They've *said* that's what they're doing, which is why I didn't tell them to just use `Array.prototype.map`. :-)